# Checking history-log of used applications last days

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android phone. Do I have a way to check my personal phone history of used applications in Log. I Want to know for example how many times the SMS application was opened and exactly opened time. Can I do it without installing any apps with Eclipse?

Comment: Ask Your Question on [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com) or [Android1](http://www.xda-developers.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.UsageStats
```

to get some usage statistics